# Woocommerce cart checkout only if specific quantities

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I would like my customers to buy either 18 or 36 products but not between the two. I wanna remove the possibility to checkout from 19 to 35.

Comment: But does they can buy from 1 to 18?

Comment: No they can't, this is the only settings I could change in the admin. They can only buy 18 or 36. Thanks

Comment: So why don't you create a product called something like "Pack of products" containing 18 same thing inside. So when a customer buy 1 product, there is really 18 product inside. And if he buy 2 of this he will get 36. You know what i mean ?

Comment: It's a store where you can buy healthy meals, there is a alot of different meals you can choose from but it takes 18 or 36 meals to complete and order.

Comment: Oh ! Not the same product you mean.

Comment: You will need to check the cart total before loading the checkout page. If it's not 18 or 36, redirect to the cart page or the shop with a message that say : "You need to have 18 or 36 product in your cart". Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: No I don't, I'm not that great with PHP, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told me in comment that you don't know php well. Most of the time we don't offer php code here, but I found it interesting to do. And it may helps some people in the future.

As I said, one possibility is to do a redirection to the cart page on the checkout page if the customer doesn't have **18** or **36** products. After the redirection on the cart page, you must display a message for the customer to see that he must have **18** or **36** products.

### Summary

- `add_action` on `template_redirect` to check the product count and handle the redirection. If we it redirects, add an arg like `invalid-cart-product-count` in the url with value **equal to the product count**.
- `add_action` on `woocommerce_before_cart` to check if we get the `invalid-cart-product-count` so we display a message.

### Working code (tested)

There is the code that you need to place in your `functions.php` file of you theme or child theme (preferred option).

```
/**
 * Check on template redirect the cart product count
 */
add_action('template_redirect','product_count_template_redirect');
function product_count_template_redirect() {

    // If we are on checkout and the cart contents count is not equal to 18 or 36
    if(is_checkout() && !in_array(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), array(18, 36))) {

        // Redirect on the cart page and add a query arg to the url so we can check for it and add a message
        wp_redirect(esc_url(add_query_arg('invalid-cart-product-count', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), wc_get_cart_url())));
        exit;
    }
}

/**
 * Handle the message on the cart page if we have the 'invalid-cart-product-count' arg in url
 */
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'cart_page_message');
function cart_page_message() {

    // If its set and not empty
    if(!empty($_GET['invalid-cart-product-count'])) {

        // Display the message with the current cart count and the count that user need to have
        $message = "<div class='woocommerce-error'>";
        $message .= sprintf(
            __('You currently have <strong>%s</strong> products in your cart. You must have <strong>18</strong> or <strong>36</strong> products in your cart to be able to checkout', 'your-text-domain'),
            // Force the arg to be an int, if someone malicious change it to anything else 
            (int) $_GET['invalid-cart-product-count']
        );
        $message .= "</div>";

        echo $message;
    }
}
```

Tell me if you don't understand or if this not exactly what you need.

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you much it's greatly appreciated you have no idea.

Comment: You're welcome. You can email me (my email is in my profile) if you need more informations.